# Latex GitHub links show with symbol

Tags: latex

I have a table with several GitHub links. I would like to replace all those links with GitHub symbol. I used fontawesome to render the symbol:

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\faGitSquare
```

I am not sure how can I replace only the GitHub links with such a symbol? Perhaps modify href? But not sure how to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\github}[1]{%
   \href{#1}{\faGithubSquare}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
\href{https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks}{\faGitSquare}    
\href{https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks}{\faGithubSquare}    
\github{https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks}            
\end{document}
```

Caveat: this won't work for comment urls that include a #

Comment: Can background of github avatar be gray than black?

Comment: @alper Sure, `\textcolor{gray}{\faGithubSquare}`

Comment: But when its href automatically it makes them blue background color

Comment: @alper Please do ask a new question if you have so specific circumstances. The example above does not use link colours.

Comment: It does as square border is blue: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/66fa166ad34f6213a168bf5a943c3887?permalink_comment_id=4135828#gistcomment-4135828